# CSS3: Integer attribute selector in CSS

Tags: css

In css i want to select element which has attribute wd and i want to set the value of width from the value of attribute wd.

```
DTD:
<!ELEMENT square EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST square wd CDATA "0">

Valid XML:
<square wd="100" />
```

i want some thing like

```
square[wd="IntegerValue"]{
  width=IntegerValue
  }
```

Comment: you'll need JS for that

Comment: Are the values of `wd` within a specific limit. Like 0-100, or, 10,20,30,...,300 or so? Or can it just be anything?

Comment: @NicolaiDitlevKroghKrüger : Value can be any integer in the range.

Comment: @maioman No we dont want to use javascript. Is this even possible through only css?

Comment: @Jitendra, in what range? It's possible to do it only in CSS, but you will might end up with a VERY long CSS file - depending on what the possible values are

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On further investigation I found out that there is CSS3 recommendation which can

```css
attr( <attr-name> <type-or-unit>? [ , <fallback> ]? )
```

we can do

square[wd="IntegerValue"]{
  width:arrr(wd,Integer)
  }

But this is not supported by any browser till now. Hope they support it in future.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```js
var wd = document.querySelectorAll('[wd]')


for(var i = 0; i < wd.length; i++){
      wd[i].style.width = wd[i].attributes.wd.value +'px'
}
```

```css
square{
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
```

```html
 <square wd="100"></square>
 <square wd="200"></square>
 <square wd="300"></square>
```

---

if you have a specific range of possible `width` you could target it directly (CSS solution) with     `square[wd='100']{width:100px}`

```css
square{
  display:block;
  height:50px;
  background:red;
  margin-bottom:10px
}
square[wd='100']{width:100px}
square[wd='200']{width:200px}
square[wd='300']{width:300px}
```

```html
 <square wd="100"></square>
 <square wd="200"></square>
 <square wd="300"></square>
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by the following ways:

```
 /* All spans with a "lang" attribute are bold */
 span[lang] {font-weight:bold;}

/* All spans in Portuguese are green */
span[lang="pt"] {color:green;}

/* All spans in US English are blue  */
span[lang~="en-us"] {color: blue;}

/* Any span in Chinese is red, matches simplified (zh-CN) or traditional (zh-TW) */
span[lang|="zh"] {color: red;}

/* All internal links have a gold background */
a[href^="#"] {background-color:gold}

/* All links to urls ending in ".cn" are red */
a[href$=".cn"] {color: red;}

/* All links to with "example" in the url have a grey background */
 a[href*="example"] {background-color: #CCCCCC;}
```

Taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

so in your example it would be

```
square[wd="100"] {
    width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: I want to support  any int value in specified range like in example width can be any value 10,20,21,23...100 .  I can not write css for every wd value. is there a generic way where i can directly feed the value of wd to width.